# Checking which elements of array have tendency to occur in pairs - pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame like this:

```
+-------------------+---------------------------+
|  movie_description|                       tags|
+-------------------+---------------------------+
|               ....|            [comedy,horror]|
|               ....|                  [romance]|
|               ....|         [thriller, sci-fi]|
|               ....| [sci-fi, horror, thriller]|
+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

How can I check, which pairs of tags occur most often with each other? There are 10 values of unique tags.

Comment: do you mean count the occurrences of the pairs?

Comment: yes, occurrences of the pairs

Comment: In your case, the output should be a new column called `output` for example with all 1s right? Because every row contains a unique combination of `tags` which is not repeated in other rows, is this what you are after?

Comment: the data frame I presented is only a part of a whole set. Of course most tags combinations are not unique.  I see it like this: pair: [comedy, horror] occurs once, pair [thriller, sci-fi] occurs twice etc.. I want to check all pairs combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a join on the same dataframe to for all possible pairs after exploding your tags, column, then perform a groupBy on each pair of tags count them then keep the max of all counts:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("A", ["comedy", "horror"]),
    ("B", ["romance"]),
    ("C", ["thriller", "sci-fi"]),
    ("D", ["sci-fi", "horror", "thriller"])
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["movie_description", "tags"])

explodedDF = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumn("tags", explode(col("tags"))).select("id", "tags")
joinDf = explodedDF.join(explodedDF.withColumnRenamed("tags", "tags2"), ["id"], "left").filter(col("tags") != col("tags2"))
pairCounts = joinDf.groupBy("tags", "tags2").count()
maxCountValue = pairCounts.agg(functions.max(col("count"))).first()[0]
max_tag_1 = pairCounts.filter(col("count") == maxCountValue).select("tags").first()[0]
max_tag_2 = pairCounts.filter(col("count") == maxCountValue).select("tags2").first()[0]
print(max_tag_1, max_tag_2)
```

Result:

thriller sci-fi

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FPGrowth](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth.html) Spark ML lib to get the frequently used tags

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size, array_sort
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, ['comedy', 'horror']),
    (1, ['romance']),
    (2, ['thriller', 'sci-fi']),
    (3, ['sci-fi', 'horror', 'thriller'])
], ["id", "items"])

# Sort tags to ignore pairs order
df = df.withColumn('items', array_sort(col('items')))

fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.1, minConfidence=0.1)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

freq_tags = model.freqItemsets.filter(size(col('items')) == 2).sort(col('freq').desc())

freq_tags.show()
```

```
+------------------+----+
|             items|freq|
+------------------+----+
|[sci-fi, thriller]|   2|
|[thriller, horror]|   1|
|  [comedy, horror]|   1|
|  [sci-fi, horror]|   1|
+------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different approach from the answers already posted. (note that the answer using the FPGrowth model seems to be the easiest, IMO).

```py
# create UDF that creates pairs for lists having 3+ tags
def createPairPermutations(arr):
    from itertools import permutations

    return [sorted(k) for k in permutations(arr, 2)]

createPairPermutations_udf = func.udf(createPairPermutations, 'Array<Array<string>>')

# create pair permutations and explode
pairs_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('tag_pair_arr', 
               func.when(func.size('tags') < 3, func.array('tags')).
               otherwise(func.array_distinct(createPermutations_udf('tags')))
               ). \
    withColumn('tag_pairs', func.explode('tag_pair_arr')). \
    withColumn('tag_pairs', func.sort_array('tag_pairs'))

# +-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
# |movie_description|tags                      |tag_pair_arr                                              |tag_pairs         |
# +-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
# |A                |[comedy, horror]          |[[comedy, horror]]                                        |[comedy, horror]  |
# |B                |[romance]                 |[[romance]]                                               |[romance]         |
# |C                |[thriller, sci-fi]        |[[thriller, sci-fi]]                                      |[sci-fi, thriller]|
# |D                |[sci-fi, horror, thriller]|[[horror, sci-fi], [sci-fi, thriller], [horror, thriller]]|[horror, sci-fi]  |
# |D                |[sci-fi, horror, thriller]|[[horror, sci-fi], [sci-fi, thriller], [horror, thriller]]|[sci-fi, thriller]|
# |D                |[sci-fi, horror, thriller]|[[horror, sci-fi], [sci-fi, thriller], [horror, thriller]]|[horror, thriller]|
# +-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+

# count occurrences of the pairs
pairs_sdf. \
    groupBy('tag_pairs'). \
    agg(func.countDistinct('movie_description').alias('freq')). \
    orderBy(func.desc('freq')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------+----+
# |tag_pairs         |freq|
# +------------------+----+
# |[sci-fi, thriller]|2   |
# |[horror, sci-fi]  |1   |
# |[comedy, horror]  |1   |
# |[horror, thriller]|1   |
# |[romance]         |1   |
# +------------------+----+
```